# How to run maven tests sequentially

Tags: java, maven, testng, sequential

I have different class with each class have one or more tests.

I want to run the maven tests with each class in a sequential order using testing.xml

testing.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1">
    <test name="Regression1">
        <classes>
            <class name="test.settings.SettingsTest"/>
            <class name="test.weather.WeatherTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

When i ran below command , its runs all the test. But i want to run the test specified in testing.xml one by one on sequential order.

```
mvn -Dtests=testing.xml test
```

Comment: Why is it important to run your tests like this. What's the underlying issue with just going with the defaults?

Comment: @AshleyFrieze I want to run test in sequential order. if i use mvn clean install. All the tests are running in parallel order.

Comment: @vikingsteve I want to run tests in any random order. But one test runs at a time. I don't want tests to run in parallel.

Comment: Okay, did you try Adrian's answer?

Comment: @vikingsteve Tried it. But tests are running in parallel.

Comment: maybe there are some options to configure `maven-surefire-plugin` ?

Comment: I suspect this could be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @karan - I think the problem is that your "I want to do Y" is hiding the X of the XY problem. What's the problem with running tests in parallel? Why does it matter the order they run? Ideally tests should be parallelisable and independent enough to run in any order? If they're not, then perhaps that's your real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have missed the configuration in maven-surefire-plugin

Here is what i tried

```
<plugins>
    [...]
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testing.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    [...]
</plugins>
```

In testing.xml

```
<test name="Regression1" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
```

its works now.

Answer (score 3):

I' not sure what you mean, but have you tried:

```
<test name="Regression1" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
```